# Using Trigonometric Functions

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

When I type Trig functions using {} or () I seem to get the same result, what is the difference between the two?

Comment: Please don't downvote below a score of -1, even if the question in it's current form needs some improvement. A score of -1 is enough to show that the question needs work, anything below that is of no use. Also, if you downvote or vote to close, please leave a comment explaining why you did so, but wait at least 24 hours after asking the OP for improvements to the question before voting to close.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They cannot be the same as follows.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt,varwidth]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\verb|$\sin{x}$ and $\sin(x)$|

$\sin{x}$ and $\sin(x)$
\end{document}
```

[image]